# Angular Material Datatable - apply filtering to custom data source

Tags: angular, angular-material, filtering

The Angular Material table tutorial shows a way of filtering data in [this document](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#filtering). The tutorial uses `MatTableDataSource<DataItem>` to demonstrate filtering. 
 However, I created data table using Angular's schematics command `ng generate @angular/material:material-table --name <component-name>`, and the data source class provided by it extends `DataSource<DataItem>`. Can it be filtered using the former method?

Answer (score 2):

The API documentation on the page you linked says [`MatTableDataSource extends DataSource`](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource) 
As `MatTableDataSource` "adds" the filter method to the interface, a simple `DataSource` can not be filtered, as it just represents data. You may check out the source code of `MatTableDataSource` at [the official github repo](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/9313f185fd5760de3368a027594a15e6cd0acaf9/src/lib/table/table-data-source.ts#L49) to fully understand what the filtering is about.

Nothing prevents you from creating a `MatTableDataSource` with your loaded data though